# The size of Amzon S3 bucket from S3 console?

Tags: amazon-s3

I wonder if there is some way to get the size of Amazon S3 bucket directly **from console** https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/
Clicking properties returns great deal of information, but not the size of the buckets in Bytes... Here is what I get when I hit properties popup...

```
Permissions
Static Website Hosting
Logging
Events
Versioning
Lifecycle
Cross-Region Replication
Tags
Requester Pays
```

I can get the info using s3cmd, but it would be convenient to have the info directly from console.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way. It requires a full crawl of the bucket to sum up each individual file's size, which is probably why it's not available there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do in the new S3 console.

Click on the bucket name, and then select the `Management` tab and then the `Metrics` button, as shown here:

[image]

You get a simple graph showing the size of the bucket over the last few days, up to 2 weeks, and also (if you scroll down a little) a graph showing the number of objects by day.

Answer (score 1):

Select the bucket you want to get the size of. Go to action button on drop.
In drop down of Action you can click get total size.